# python take picture with cv2 -Dirty picture

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, python

I tried to take a photo with cv2 and when I open the image file, the picture is very dirty. i mean, there are a lots of stains.
And the image layout is not good at all, not only because of my camera
my code:

```
import time
import cv2
camera_port = 0
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)
time.sleep(0.1) 
return_value, image = camera.read()
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", image)
del(camera)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to clean your lens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by layout you mean that the image is stretched, then set capture dimensions to something your camera supports, via

```
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
```

Assuming you're using a laptop webcam, you might be encountering a situation where the camera needs to 'warm up'. Consider discarding the first few frames before saving one. One an old ThinkPad I use, I have to discard the first 8 images before getting a good one.